# how to run asp.net application under local user account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to run my ASP.NET MVC 5 application under a local user account. I tried adding below line in web.config

```
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="LocalUserName" password="password" />
```

However, it's giving the error

> unable to start debugging on web server. The web server did not respond in timely manner.

Actually, the system just hangs when I hit F5 to run the application, and then I get the above timeout error after a few minutes.

am I doing something wrong ? any suggestions ?

Comment: thanks for the response. error is : "unable to start debugging on web server. The web server did not respond in timely manner". actually system just hangs when I hit F5 to run the application and then I get above timeout error after few minutes

Comment: Does this help? http://forums.asp.net/t/1416456.aspx?unable+to+start+debugging+on+the+web+server+the+web+server+did+not+respond+in+a+timely+manner+this+may+be+because+another+debugger+is+already+attached+to+the+web+server+

Comment: Why not run the app in an app pool that uses the local user account?

Comment: Are you doing local or remote debugging?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are doing remote debugging.

Here is an excerpt from Microsoft - [Recap of debugging permissions in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893658)

> The debugging user must be in the Administrators group on the server
>   OR the debugging user must “own” the process and be in the Debugger
>   Users group or the Administrators group. When I say “own” the process,
>   this means that the identity of the ASP.NET worker process must be the
>   same as the debugging user’s credentials. This is done with the
>    section of the machine.config in Windows XP and in
>   Windows 2000 or with the AppPool identity in Windows Server 2003.
>   Also, this is the only way to let a developer perform remote debugging
>   without having administrative credentials on the remote Web server.
>   The following KB article explains this as well. This particular
>   article states the minimum permissions for debugging in Visual Studio
>   .NET. However, this article is often overlooked when trying to
>   troubleshoot debugging problems.